# An open problem on general topology

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, open-problem

There is an open problem in this paper:

J. van Mill, V.V. Tkachuk, R.G. Wilson, "[Classes defined by stars and neighbourhood assignments](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864107000193)", Topology and its Applications, Vol. 154, Issue 10, 2007, pp. 2127–2134.

**Problem 4.8.** Is a regular star compact space metrizable if it has a $G_\delta$-diagonal?

A topological space $X$ is said to be star compact if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$. 
More on star compactness see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94172/how-far-is-being-star-compact-from-being-countably-compact).

My question is this: Is always the cardinality of such regular star compact space less than $2^{\omega_0}$?

Thanks for any help. Any help to solve such open problem is very welcome.

Comment: Probably you mean "less or equal than $2^{\omega_0}$", because even usual segment which is a metrizable compact, has cardinality $2^{\omega_0}$.